# MySQL UNION query Syntax issue

Tags: mysql, join, syntax, syntax-error, union

Let's say that I want to get records from 2 different tables (which have the same structure) by using UNION.

The query is something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM (

(SELECT `a1`.`title`, `a1`.`updated_date`, `a1`.`plain_description`, `a1`.`thumb`, `a1`.`link`, `c1`.`alias` as category_alias
FROM (`articles1` as a1) 
LEFT JOIN `article_categories1` as c1 ON `c1`.`id`=`a1`.`category_id` 
WHERE `a1`.`visible` = 1 AND `c1`.`alias` = 'category-alias' AND `c1`.`visible` = 1) 

UNION 

(SELECT `a2`.`title`, `a2`.`updated_date`, `a2`.`plain_description`, `a2`.`thumb`, `a2`.`link`, `c2`.`alias` as category_alias 
FROM (`articles2` as a2) 
LEFT JOIN `article_categories2` as c2 ON `c2`.`id`=`a2`.`category_id` 
WHERE `a2`.`visible` = 1 AND `c2`.`visible` = 1)

) as t ORDER BY t.updated_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

When I execute the query it shows :

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN `article_categories2` as c2 ON `c2`.`id`=`a2`.`category_id`
```

What was wrong here?

```
**`UPDATED`**
```

Remove parentheses in sub queries solved the problem.
Just one more thing, how could I add a field to each record that would tell me which table it belong to.
Assume that I want to have something like this:

```
id     |    title     | link            | table
-----------------------------------------------------
1      | Title 1      | somelink.html   | articles1
2      | Title 2      | link2   .html   | articles2
3      | Title 3      | link3   .html   | articles1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove a few parentheses

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT `a1`.`title`, `a1`.`updated_date`, `a1`.`plain_description`, `a1`.`thumb`, `a1`.`link`, `c1`.`alias` as category_alias
FROM `articles1` as a1 
LEFT JOIN `article_categories1` as c1 ON `c1`.`id`=`a1`.`category_id` 
WHERE `a1`.`visible` = 1 AND `c1`.`alias` = 'category-alias' AND `c1`.`visible` = 1

UNION 

SELECT `a2`.`title`, `a2`.`updated_date`, `a2`.`plain_description`, `a2`.`thumb`, `a2`.`link`, `c2`.`alias` as category_alias 
FROM `articles2` as a2 
LEFT JOIN `article_categories2` as c2 ON `c2`.`id`=`a2`.`category_id` 
WHERE `a2`.`visible` = 1 AND `c2`.`visible` = 1

) as t 
ORDER BY t.updated_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: Thanks. It works with your solution. But why? Can you give me an explaination?

Comment: I think the problem is if you put a complete select in parentheses it becomes a subselect that needs to be aliased.